# Amounts of oil in the menachos

Tags: oil, mincha-meal-offering, olive-oil, korban-todah

Different menachos contain different amounts of oil. Standard nesachim had a lot of oil. For instance, the נסכים for a lamb were one עשרון of fine flour with three לוג of olive oil.

For context, an עשרון is a shiur challah, so think of a four-pound bag of flour (or a little less). A reviis is a quarter of a לוג, call it three ounces, so a לוג is about the volume of a 12 oz. can of soda.

Okay, so three soda cans of oil into a four-pound bag of flour: a lot of oil.

On the other hand, a regular mincha was one עשרון of flour and one לוג of oil, a single soda can and a four-pound bag of flour: still a significant amount of oil.

But now look at a korban Todah. The gemara in [Menachos 89a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.89a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) uses a drasha (שמן שמן אין ריבוי אחר ריבוי אלא למעט) to say that it contains *less* oil, only half a לוג. It says there that the half-log was divided as follows: The chametz bread did not contain any oil at all. The רבוכה had extra oil, so it got half, a quarter לוג (a "revi'is", actually). The other two types (challos and wafers) got the other half, an eighth of a לוג each. Not so much.

But now it is being divided among ten loaves each! Each of the four types used ten עשרונות of flour: ten four-pound bags of flour. Into that we are mixing (in various ways for the different types) a revi'is of oil, or half a revi'is.

In numbers, if a revi'is is 1.5 ביצה, and an עשרון = shiur challah = 43.2 ביצה, this is a mixture of 1.5 into 432, or for the other types .75 into 432. Much less than one in sixty, less than one in two hundred - close to indetectable?

The gemara there (and Rashi in Chumash) makes a big deal out of how the רבוכה is called "שמן" because it contains "extra" oil - compared to the other two!

Has anyone seen an explanation of why we are mixing in such a tiny amount of oil?

Comment: Maybe because they are not in the category of a מנחה - they aren’t called that in the Torah; also compare it to the לחם הפנים and the שתי הלחם, which containd no oil at all!

Comment: @שלום It is true that the gemara and the Rambam emphasize that it isn't a mincha. I wouldn't have had a question if there were no oil; as you say, other menachos have no oil (and also the chametz part of the lachmei todah). I was surprised that there was oil, but such a miniscule amount.